# Checked value not reflecting for dynamically created Checkboxes asp.net c# jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I'm having few checkboxes which are dynamically created using c# code- behind.
At client side using jquery I want to make the checkbox as checked, but the checked value is not reflected on the UI. I have browsed for the solution and it suggest something related to VIEWSTATE. Here is my C# code and Jquery where I'm setting the Checkbox value.

C#. Code

```
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();
            checkbox.ID = "CheckBox" + i++;
            checkbox.InputAttributes["class"] = "skin-line-grey icheck-label form-label";
            checkbox.ClientIDMode = ClientIDMode.Static;
            checkbox.Text = item.Text;
            PnlEventList.Controls.Add(checkbox);
```

Jquery. Checkbox1 is the ID for checkbox been dynamically created. Same I have 7 more checkboxes.

```
$('#CheckBox1').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: Did you try using class instead of id?

Comment: Have you included jquery reference file in your page ?

Comment: Take care of case sensitivity. Checkbox1 or CheckBox1

Comment: Make sure jQuery is included and when code is executed the checkbox is present in DOM, $('#CheckBox1').length should be one if it is present in dom.

Comment: Yes I have tried using a class instead of id and I have also given jquery reference file as I have already used a lot of javascript into my application.

Comment: Yes the id is proper I have already cross checked it various times. I have even used ClientIDMode as static. This is the html generated after running the application.

<input id="CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CheckBox1" class="skin-line-grey icheck-label form-label" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">

Comment: Yes the $('#CheckBox1') is present in the DOM and the CheckBox1 value is changing to true, but its not reflecting on the UI. I have inserted the debugger and checked. Here is the attribute value.


accept: ""
accessKey: ""
align: ""
alt: ""
assignedSlot: null
attributes: NamedNodeMap
autocapitalize: "none"
autocomplete: ""
autofocus: false
baseURI: "http://localhost:38843/CreateUser.aspx"
checked:true
childElementCount: 0
childNodes: NodeList[0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CheckBox property, lying not in properties or attribute collection. Use this:

```
$('#CheckBox1')[0].checked = true;
```

Or this:

```
document.getElementById("CheckBox1").checked = true;
```

Comment: As I already mentioned before. The Checked attribute is getting true but it is not reflecting on the UI. The checkbox is still shown un-checked and vice-versa.

Comment: @Sergio $('#CheckBox1').checked = true; would give error as jQuery object returned by selector does not have property .checked. It could be $('#CheckBox1')[0].checked = true;

Comment: This works, There was a problem with my css style so the value was not reflecting with my UI.

Answer (score -1):

Try this: `$('#Checkbox1').prop('checked', true);`
This is case sensitive.